# Selecting an element within another, is this method valid? If not, how do i go about it?

Tags: jquery, forms, input

```
<table class="tableData" id="addUserTable" >
    <tr>
        <th class = "" name="errorMsgUser" id="errorMsg" value="" colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class= "" > Desired Username <span class="required">*</span></th>
        <td><input name="desUname" type="text" id="desUname" size="30" value=""  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class= "" > Password <span class="required">*</span></th>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td>
            <input name="submitAddUser" type="submit" id="submitAddUser" value="Add User" />
            <input type="button" value="Clear All" id="clearUpdateForm"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the button "clearUpdateForm" is click, I've managed to clear all the form entries.How do I then focus the first input text-box ? I want a generic solution. This is my jquery script so far :

```
    $(function(){$("#clearUpdateForm").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('form').find(':input').each(function() {
            switch(this.type) {
                case 'password':
                case 'select-multiple':
                case 'select-one':
                case 'text':
                case 'textarea':
                    $(this).val('');
                    break;
                case 'checkbox':
                case 'radio':
                    this.checked = false;
            }});
        $('input#desUname').focus();    
    });});
```

Can i replace the last lin of code by these two lines:

```
    var parentId = "#" + $(this).parents('form').attr("id") ;
    $("parentId input[type=text]:first").focus();
```

Comment: @roXon, I did, and thanks for the welcome, love this site !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

last line can be replaced by

```
    var parent = $(this).closest('form');
    parent.find('input[type=text]:first').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you change the second line to:

```
  $(parentId+" input[type=text]:first").focus();
```

Or you can simply use:

```
$(this).parents('form').find('input:first').focus();
```

This way it will work even if the form does not have any ID.